# How to get the intersection of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of similar format:

```
df1 = DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4], 'b':['q','r','s','t','u']})
df1

    a   b
0   0   q
1   1   r
2   2   s
3   3   t
4   4   u

df2 = DataFrame({'a':[4,3,2,1,999], 'b':['u','r','s','t','u']})
df2

    a   b
0   4   u
1   3   r
2   2   s
3   1   t
4   999 u
```

I would like to get a new dataframe that has rows that appear in both of these (ignoring the index). So the above example gives a dataframe

```
    a   b
0   4   u
1   2   s
```

How do I get this intersection?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just perform a [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge), this will use all columns and the default type of merge is `inner` so values must be present in both dfs:

```
In [71]:

df1.merge(df2)
Out[71]:
   a  b
0  2  s
1  4  u
```